# using Databinder.Eval in onclick of checkbox in datagrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, datagrid, databinder

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dg" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" onclick='myCheckChanged("<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.myid")%>")' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

This runs but when I click the checkbox in the browser I get a js error.  I tried all the combinations of single and double quotes and escaping but i either get a js error or a .net "The server tag is not well formed" error.  how can I do this?

Comment: figured out a way, here's what I did:     <asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" onclick=<%# "myCheckChanged('" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "myid") + "') "%> />

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code it will show you `undefined` or nothing so there are some ways to do this approach, the firs one and easiest you should change you `cb` as following:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" onclick='<%# string.Format("myCheckChanged(\"{0}\")", Eval("myid")) %>' />
```

and the second way you can do it in `code-behind` on `ItemDataBound` like this:

1- change your `DataGrid' as:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dg" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dg_ItemDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

2- in `code-behind` implement `dg_ItemDataBound` like :

```
 protected void dg_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            CheckBox ch = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("cb");
            ch.Attributes.Add("OnClick", string.Format("myCheckChanged({0});", e.Item.Cells[1].Text));
        }
    }
```

note: in this snippet `e.Item.Cells[1].Text` you must know `myid` is in which `Cells`

these two ways are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

figured out a way, here's what I did:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="server" onclick=<%# "myCheckChanged('" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "myid") + "') "%> />
```